# why is s1 reading a null character?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#pragma
int main()
{
  char s1[5];
  char s2[5];
  scanf("%s%s",s1,s2);//enter apple in both cases
  printf("%s",s1);
}
```

My question is that after i enter a string of size same as the size of my character array s1 why is s1 reading a null ?

Comment: you got undefined behavior there. "apple" is 6 characters due to the null character at the end, you only got arrays of 5 chars.

Comment: `scanf` is not a good way to read strings.  Use `fgets()` instead and then parse the line by inspecting the string returned..

Comment: Extending on @RaphaelMiedl's comment, you should have done something like `char s1[5+1];`.

Comment: Using `scanf` is OK but change `%s` to `%4s` (the number has to be 1 less than the size of your array)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
scanf("%4s%4s", s1, s2);
```

to limit the input to 4 characters leaving the 5th (last) one for the null character (`\0`). The result of the new code will be this:

```
[user@so ~]$ ./a.out
Enter s1 and s2: apple apple
s1 = `appl`
s2 = `e`
```

This happens because `scanf` continues to read the second string where it finished the first one. And because `s1` is limited to 4 characters, the reading of `s2` will continue from the character `e`.

```
        ┌──────first %4s stops after reading 4 characters and
        │      stores "appl" into s1
        ▼
a│p│p│l│e│ │a│p│p│l│e        'a'│'p'│'p'│'l'│ 0       'e'│ 0 │ ? │ ? │ ?
─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─     s1 ───┼───┼───┼───┼───   s2 ───┼───┼───┼───┼───
0│1│2│3│4│5│6│7│8│9│          0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4        0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4
          ▲
          │
          └──────second %4s stops at the first whitespace and
                 stores "e" into s2
```

The results for other inputs:

```
[user@so ~]$ ./a.out
Enter s1 and s2: appleapple
s1 = `appl`
s2 = `eapp`
[user@so ~]$ ./a.out
Enter s1 and s2: abc 123456
s1 = `abc`
s2 = `1234`
```

Comment: but when i am printing s2 apple gets printed y is it so?

Comment: @user3720783, I've updated my answer, maybe it's more clear to you now.

Answer (score -1):

because when ever you enter the any name in the string compiler automatically place null after the word you enter.
and it never print the null